# Reference for studying the method of stationary phase

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I would like to learn about the stationary phase method, as part of the theory of Fourier Integral Operators.

From what I can see so far, Hormander's book "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I" seems to be the standard reference, but I was wondering whether somebody has some positive experience with alternative textbooks that I could use to supplement Hormander's exposition, in case it gets too dense.

Many thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learnt the stationary phase method from Thomas Wolff's: Lectures on Harmonic Analysis. I supplemented it with Hörmander's but I found Hörmander a bit difficult on first reading.

Stein's "big book" Harmonic Analysis is also a standard superb reference.

Also, check out Tao's lecture notes http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/